# How to add qtranslate lang switcher button in custom admin page

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, qtranslate

I have my custom post type "**soto_property**" and a custom admin page with URL "**/edit.php?post_type=soto_property&page=properties.php**" in my wordpress site backend.

I have used "**qtranslate-x**" plugin to make my site multilingual.

Now I want to show **qtranslate language switcher buttons** on my custom admin page also as these buttons are showing up already in custom post type page, post and pages.

I have set its url "edit.php?post_type=soto_property&page=properties.php" in the field **Custom Admin Pages** on settings page of qtranslate-x plugin .

But still language buttons are missing from my custom admin page.

What can I do to show these buttons on my custom admin page.

Comment: AFAIK, there was never a setting in the Admin panel options of qTranslate for custom admin panel urls. But there are options to add custom places from the json config and you can add custom id at input fields so that LSB works for them too.

Answer (score 0):

I think now (after many years of updates) you can see language switcher buttons in all WP admin pages ;)